# Efficient storage of functional data

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, dataset, computational-statistics, functional-data-analysis

I have access to a sample (size $N$) of functional data. Each observation corresponds to $C$ functions. Each function $f_{n,c}$ is represented by $T_n$ points for $1\geq n \geq N, 1\geq c \geq C$. All $N, C, T_n$ are in the order of $1e2$ to $1e4$. It is prohibitive to store every $f_{n,c}$.

How do I efficiently store each observation's functions efficiently?

For more context, these data come from a computer process, where it is reasonable to temporarily store $f_{n,c}$ as a vector of points, but not all of them all at once.

I am thinking of summarizing the functions via  spline approximations and storing the parameters instead. Is there a more fundamentally sound approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) $B$. Each time we get new data point, we project it in that basis, repeat. That way we are storing only the coefficients and a single copy of the basis functions. The obvious choice of a basis is to do an [Functional PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_principal_component_analysis) on our data. If we cannot/do not want to do that, a parametric basis should do mostly fine to. Example: [JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) was effectively a 2D [discrete cosine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). Assuming one does not go fully non-parametric with the FPCA, at first instance, I would suggest looking at [wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) as they are the most flexible in terms of time- as well as frequency-domain. There is a slew of papers available for "wavelets on functional data", so I will mention two books:

1. [Wavelet Methods in Statistics with R](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-75961-6) (2008) by Nason.
2. [Wavelets in Functional Data Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-59623-5) (2017) by Morettin et al.

For a quick starter, I just saw this BSc thesis on [Wavelet Representations for functional data](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/70984/1/) (2019) by Lorenz and it's pretty decent if you want to get started too!
In any case, given we have defined our functional basis, reconstructing our original data $D$ is just taking our stored coefficients and using them to build this *reduced dimensionality" approximation $\hat{D}$. The error is going to be controlled by the expressiveness our basis $B$.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting so many solutions! A quick follow-up: how do you select the eigefunctioms in FPCA apriori to collecting (and storing) a full sample?

Comment: We pick the first $k$ because they give us the best approximation. Hm... That is a good side question, the obvious answer is to perform incremental PCA. The other option is to store a random subset, for that matter see the concept of "[Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)", it generalises directly to any data unit (in this case time-series/function).

Comment: Thanks again :).

Comment: Happy to help! :)